# Sharepoint using free servers

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I have to look at the Microsoft Sharepoint Designer, i have the Designer installed but to not assemble all the dependencies of Microsoft Sharepoint Server (windows 2008 server 64, sql server, etc, etc...) i'm asking if Microsoft (or someone) has a free site to provide us a Microsoft Sharepoint Server installed to test the designer on it, maybe exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the virtual labs:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/cc707678.aspx

Or download a pre-configured virtual machine with everything already installed:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=27417

But the answer to your actual question I suspect is no. Sharepoint costs alot of money for an external licence, it's unlikely that anybody, even Microsoft, is going to open up a sharepoint server for you especially when they are giving away virtual machines that do just that. Plus all the dangers from hackers etc to the next user that comes along. Get the VM going.